# Most efficient way to clean data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need some help cleaning my data...

I have a BQ table where I receive new entries from my back-end, these data are recorded to my BQ and I'm using Google Data Studio to present these data.

My problem is, I a field named `sessions` that sometimes are duplicates, I can't solve that directly in my back-end because a user can send different data from the same session so I can't just stop recording duplicates.

I've managed my problem by creating a View that selects the newest duplicate record and I'm using this view as data-source for my report. The problem with this approach is that I lost the feature of  `"real-time report"` and that is important in this case. And another problem is that I also lost `Accelerated by BigQuery BI Engine` and I would like to have these feature too.

Is this the best solution for my problem and I'll need to accept this outcome or there is another way?

Many thanks in advance, kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Using the view should work for BI Engine acceleration. Can you please share more details on BI Engine? It should show you the reason query wasn't accelerated, likely mentioning one of the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/introduction#limitations). If you hover over "not accelerated" sign it should give you more details on why your query wasn't supported. Feel free to share it here and I will be happy to help.

Another way you can clean up the data: Have scheduled job to preprocess the data. It will mean data may not be the most recent, but it will give you ability to clean up and aggregate data.